# Is it possible to use member functions as callbacks without an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, oop, member-functions

If I want to apply a function to a single object, I can do it like this:

```js
> 'mystr'.toUpperCase()
'MYSTR'
```

But if I want to do the same for an array, using `map` (for example), I must do it like this:

```js
> ['one','two','three'].map((x)=>x.toUpperCase(x))
[ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]
```

Is there a way to use this functions without the dot notation? For example

```
// THIS DOESN'T WORK, BUT I WANT TO ACHIEVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS
> String.toUpperCase('mystr')
'MYSTR'
> ['one','two','three'].map(String.toUpperCase)
[ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]
```

---

These are just examples, I don't give me specific solutions for using `map` or `toUpperCase`, please. I just want to know if member functions can be used as callback functions without an anonymous extra function

Comment: `String.toUpperCase` still uses dot notation...

Comment: Do you mean `String.prototype.toUpperCase.call("mystr")`? or perhaps something like `function toUpper(text) { return typeof text === "string" ? text.toUpperCase() : ""; }` and `toUpper("mystr")`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean that you don't need an existing object to put the dot and then apply it. I'll try to rephrase that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without creating another function, no. You'll end up creating a function either way.

But it can be a reusable one:

```js
// Reusable function
const makeUpper = str => str.toUpperCase();

// Using it
console.log(["one","two","three"].map(makeUpper));
```

You can also create the function with `bind`, but it's pretty convoluted to read:

```js
// Reusable function
const makeUpper = Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase);

// Using it
console.log(["one","two","three"].map(makeUpper));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it more proper (and less confusing) to do `Function.prototype.call.bind(String.prototype.toUpperCase)`? 
Or `$.call.bind("".toUpperCase)` for short.

Comment: @nickzoum - I wouldn't call it more or less proper. I don't know whether that would confuse people more or less. (But certainly not the `$` version, there's no jQuery here. :) ) I do kind of like `Function.prototype.call` better, yeah.

Comment: I meant the `Function.prototype.call` was more appropriate, the `$` part was just a short option. Pretty sure all the browsers have a short `$` implementation, which only returns the first element found, instead of the full list, can't find any documentation on it though.

Comment: @nickzoum - Only in the console, not in actual code. Try this in various browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ytmdupLn/

Answer (score 0):

`map` calls the function that you pass it for every item in the array passing the current item as the first argument.

Functions like `toUpperCase` don't take any arguments (in your example you pass `x` but it is ignored). They expect the value they operate on to be `this`.

So, no. You can't just pass a function which expects `this` to be significant to `map`.